# Strange behavior of CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, opencv, cuda

I am trying to make a simple Cuda application that creates integral image of given matrix. One of the steps I need to do, is to create integral image of every row. In order to do this, I want to assign 1 thread to each row. Function that is supposed to do this:

```
__global__ void IntegrateRows(const uchar* img, uchar* res)
{
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (x >= Width || y >= Height)
        return;

    int sum = 0;
    int row = y * Width;
    for (int i = 0; i < Width - x; ++i)
    {
        res[row + i + x] = sum + img[row + i + x];
        sum += img[row + i + x];
    }
}
```

I use a matrix of size 3840x2160 filled with ones (`cv::Mat::ones(Size(Width, Height), CV_8UC1)`) for tests. When I try to print out content of the result, it always returns sequence of numbers from 1 to 255:
[image: Console output]

The execution configurations is:

```
dim3 threadsPerBlock(1, 256);
dim3 numBlocks(1, 16);
IntegrateRows<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock >>>(img, res);
```

My GPU is Nvidia RTX 3090.

Comment: res is type unsigned char. 255 is max you can store on 8 bits type. Change res matrix type to wider, 16 or 32 bits integer.

Comment: OpenCV matrices use pitched memory AFAIK. I very much doubt your indexing is correct, even after you fix the 8 bit integer overflow error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr: Make your output matrix have larger elements**

If you integrate/prefix-sum the sequence

1, 1, 1, 1, ...

You get:

0, 1, 2, 3, ...

and this sequence will wrap around to 0 when you reach the maximum value of your element type. In your case, it's a `uchar`, i.e. `unsigned char`. And its maximum value is 255. Add another 1 to it, and you get 0. So: 0, 1, 2, 3, ... 253, 254, 255, 0, 1, ... and so on.

If you change the output matrix element type to `unsigned short` (or maybe simply `unsigned int`) - you won't get the wrap-around behavior. Of course, if you add up 255's instead of 1's, and/or your matrix is larger, then again the type's represented range might not be large enough.